# How to set a richtext box in Pencil to a custom width?

Tags: firefox-addon, wireframe, evolus-pencil

I'm creating a prototype with [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/) an open source wireframing and mocking tool. I need to add a rich text box to my prototype and fill it with some sample text. The problem is that the box automatically resizes itself to around 200px and it won't budge from that width no matter what I do.

I need to know how to set a custom width for a pencil rich text box.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pencil, but it doesn't sound like this question is really related to firefox addons.

Comment: Pencil is not exclusively a Firefox add-on. A standard desktop version is also available (also free). Just adding for clarity for future readers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible you've already figured this out. Right click the rich text field, look for "fixed width", click it, drag the little yellow box to whatever width you want.

I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Also, the mouse icon is an arrow for dragging the yellow box, at least on Mac. I kept tri-ying to use the hand, which moves other UI elements...